# jstree: how to make resulting nodes (with children) from a search expandable?

Tags: tree, jstree, expandable, collapsable

I'm working with the following tree fiddle: [searchable jstree fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3430245/07x435yg/9/)

My question is, how do I make resulting nodes from a search expandable? Example: in the fiddle above, the 'Orange County' node has three child nodes. If I drill down to 'Orange County' manually, I can expand it and see the child nodes. However, if I type in 'Orange County' in the search box, I lose the ability to expand 'Orange County' to see the child nodes.

Thanks in advance!
Below is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <input class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search term"/>
</div>
<div id="SampleContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>
      NORTH
      <ul>
        <li>
          ORANGE COUNTY
          <ul>
            <li>
              GANGLAND
            </li>
            <li>
              MOTOWN
            </li>
            <li>
              CARLSBAD
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          BLUE COUNTY
          <ul>
            <li>
              SANFRAN
            </li>
            <li>
              ZOOTOWN
            </li>
            <li>
              GUETECH
            </li>
            <li>
              D
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$.jstree.defaults.search.show_only_matches = true;
$.jstree.defaults.search.show_only_matches_children = false;
$.jstree.defaults.search.search_leaves_only = false;
$(function() {
  $(".search-input").keyup(function() {
    var searchString = $(this).val();
    console.log(searchString);
    $('#SampleContainer').jstree('search', searchString);
  });

  $("#SampleContainer").jstree({
    "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox", "search"],
    core: {
      "themes": {
        "icons": false,
        "dots": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "stripes": true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I figured it out. I had to set $.jstree.defaults.search.show_only_matches to false instead of true.